# getting input from button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Below is my html code for the form

```
 <form id="taxi_distance_input" >




<div class="col-md-8" style="display: inline-block; left:-30px">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="input-group">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"> </input>
<span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 50px">km</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0px; margin-left:-10px">

 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" id="myButton"> </input>

</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

And in the bottom of the page I give the

```
<script src="/js/form_input_parameter.js"></script>
```

Inside the form_input_parameter.js i have written the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        var text =  $("#usr").val();
        alert(text+"success");
 });
```

But it is not working .Any help is apprecited

Comment: Missing `});`, Seems error occurred while posting question.

Comment: Have you included jquery plugin ?

Comment: Works fine here with proper close braces https://jsfiddle.net/n6ste5hh/ Note that `<input>` is a self closing tag

Comment: have you included jquery before your form_input_parameter.js and as Satpal said check the closing braces are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You've forgotten the `});` at the end of your JS code
2. The `input` tag should end with `/>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myButton').click(function() {
    var text = $("#usr").val();
    alert(text + " success");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" id="myButton" />
```

Comment: Code only answers are virtually meaningless. At least provide an explanation